# Java - asking questions x times depending on the users answer

Tags: java

I want to ask three questions x times depending on the answer and then I want to calculate the total cost of depending on the answers given. I'm wondering if this way works and if so how do I calculate the total cost?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("x ingredients?");
    int amount = sc.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= amount; i++) { 
        System.out.print("Nr " + i + ": How much do you have?\n");
        int have = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Nr " + i + ": How much do you need?\n");
        int need = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Nr " + i + ": How much does it cost?");
        int cost = sc.nextInt();
        if(i == amount) {
            // calculate total cost 
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What formula you are using to calculate the Total Cost?

Comment: You are asking us if it works. Did you run it to see for yourself? Did it work?

Comment: You're on the right track. You need to declare another variable before the for loop to hold the total cost. Then inside the loop add to the total cost the cost of the current iteration. Something like `total = total + ((need - have) * cost)`. Make sure to check `need - have` is greater than zero, otherwise don't add anything to `total`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the total cost outside of the loop, otherwise it will go out of scope. For example, before the loop, initialize the total cost:

```
int totalCost = 0; //you used sc.nextInt() so I assume no decimals
```

Then, in the loop, just get the amount to buy and multiply by the cost.

```
int toBuy = need - have;
//you do NOT need if (i == amount) because you will add to the cost whenever it's necessary, not just at the end of the loop
if (toBuy > 0){ //don't buy things you don't need
    totalCost += toBuy * cost;
}
```

Then, outside the loop, print the total cost:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++){
    //...
}
System.out.println("Total cost of ingredients: " + totalCost);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, didn't expect to get answers so fast. It doesn't calculate everything at the end. I want to have like 2 ingredients and calculate the cost of both combined (which is why I asked if this code would work) Thanks for helping

Comment: Does this not work? Remember this is _in_ the loop. If you have `if (i == amount)` then it will only run at the very end (and all variables from the previous iteration(s) will be lost)

Comment: Apparently it works, but if I want for example 2 ingredients, it prints out the totalcost after the questions for the first ingredient, but after I've answered the questions for both ingredients it calculates both as it should. I don't want it to print out the totalcost before I've answered all these questions for all ingredients. Cheers

Comment: See my edit. Note that I never put a print statement in the loop. You added that.

Comment: It works perfectly. Sorry for being so unclear with my questions. Thanks for helping :)